# Image Magick: % character in caption not appearing

Tags: imagemagick

I am using this command to add a caption to an image:

```
convert -background black -bordercolor black -fill white -size 300x20 -pointsize $myFontsize caption:$title -trim -border 5 -channel A -fx '(lightness/2)+.8' -geometry +$myX+$myY $input +swap -composite $output
```

but when $title contains a % character, it is not visible in the caption, nor is the space character following the %.

For instance, if $title = "India contributes to 75% of the global spice production", the caption will read "India contributes to 75of the global spice production"

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Not sure what shell and OS you are using but you need to double-quote shell variables `convert -pointsize 36 caption:"$title" result.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-11-29 Q16 on Ubuntu 14.04. Double quoting the $title variable did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Image Magick "caption:", "%" is a special character, so we can do things like this:

```
convert -size 300x300 caption:"Width is %w" x.png
```

so the solution is to escape each % with another % (put double %). If the caption is in a variable $title:

```
title=`echo $title | sed s/%/%%/g`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example that should work fine:

```
title="India contributes to 75% of the global spice production"
convert -background cyan -pointsize 36 caption:"$title" result.jpg
```

[image]

If that doesn't work on your system, you should check you are not using a shell that does something mad with variables, and after that, consider upgrading your **ImageMagick** to a newer version from the last 4-5 years.

Alternatively, you could try supplying the string through `stdin` as follows:

```
echo "India contributes to 75% of the global spice production" | convert -background cyan -pointsize 36 caption:@- result.jpg
```

Comment: I get this error when I try your commands: "convert.im6: unknown image property "% " @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3164." How do I check my shell does not do something bad with variables? I'm using the regular ubuntu terminal. And isn't my ImageMagick version from 4 months ago? The stdin command you gave me writes @- on the image

Comment: Your ImageMagick is around 4-5 years old, we have had 6.8, 6.9 and 7.0 since your version. What shell do you use - you can run `echo $0` to find out or look for your username in `/etc/passwd` and find it there. Did you copy and paste my exact commands, or type them in - even the spaces are critical.

Comment: yes I copy and pasted your commands. My shell is bash. I read here http://askubuntu.com/questions/722797/update-imagemagick-ubuntu that imagemagick 6.7 is the current version for ubuntu 14.04, so I'd prefer to keep using it in order not to break other stuff (the IM script I'm using is for work)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what is wrong if neither of those two commands work.